# How to upgrade an iPad to iOS 8 from iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ipad, upgrade, software-update

I have an iPad running iOs 7.x

I want to install an app which requires iOs 8.0 or newer. But for compatibility reasons I can't install iOs 9.x yet, as it may break some existing app.

Is there a way to install iOS 8 from iOS 7 ?

P.S. If it's possible I'd rather not to downgrade, that is I would like to install directly iOs 8 instead of installing 9 and then downgrading to 8 somehow.

Comment: It's not a downgrade... But an upgrade to a specific version.

Comment: Agreed, but the problem and the answer are the same. Apple doesn't sign iOS 8 any longer.

Comment: Sure, but the question is worthy for an answer. I mean, upgrade and downgrade are not the same, so the duplicate is quite ambiguous.

Comment: @patrix Yeah, the fact the the problem is the same as in the downgrade case is not immediately clear to everybody (certainly not to me. I saw the "downgrade" questions before posting but I figured it was different). So an answer like "As in the downgrade case, it's not possible due to  Apple not signing the certificate" may be in order. In any case I don't particularly care about this being open or closed so decide and let me know :)

Comment: Problem solved, original of duplicate edited to include upgrade as well as downgrade. The end result is the same, I'm afraid - so long as your device is still eligible for the current iOS, there is no way to go from an older iOS to **any** intermediate version, or back to that version. BTW, closing a question as a duplicate is often beneficial as it makes the answer **more** likely to be found by future Googlers.

Comment: My answer here explains everything: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387