# iPhone 5C downgrade iOS 9 to iOS 8

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, downgrade

I bit the bullet and upgraded to iOS 9.1, and the phone now moves like it's an iPhone 3GS. I can see iOS 8.x is no longer signed, but fortunately I have SHSH of iOS 8.2 saved.

How can I downgrade without losing my warranty?
I've heard jailbraking will void warranty, but I guess jailbraking then flashing an iOS version that removes the jailbreak should allow my phone to still be in warranty.

PS: This is not a duplicate of [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r), because it talks about restoring from IOS9 to usinged IOS8 version with SHSH blobs.

Comment: Jailbreak won't void your warranty, as you can always restore the device to the newest (non-jailbroken) version.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, unless you saved your signature while iOS 8 was still being signed. Without a saved signature, there's no way for anyone except Apple to install iOS 8 on any device.

Comment: You mean a SHSH blob? I've saved those, but don't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreak will prevent Apple from providing you service/support. As mentioned in the other comments restoring to the current iOS will fix that. The main question that hasn't been posed is : "What is the memory storage of your device?" Current versions of iOS have been optimized for upgraded hardware but you shouldn't experience that drastic of a reduction in overall phone performance. The first thing I'd look at is how much storage am I using before the OS.