# Why can't I install iOS 9.3?

Tags: upgrade, software-update, restore, ios

I saw an update for my iOS 9.2.1 device to iOS 9.3.

However, it said that the update cannot be verified, although it was downloaded.

I even deleted all data and applications from the device, but I still cannot update the device to 9.3; it just says "Your software is up to date" on iOS 9.2.1.

Can you force an update to 9.3?

Comment: Apple fixed the problem today. Try updating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apple yanked iOS 9.3 (13E233)](https://ipsw.me/updates) for almost all devices on 03/24/16 which means you can't install it. And no, [you cannot force an update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387) to iOS 9.3 since Apple is no longer signing it.

**Update: iOS 9.3 (13E237) has been released on 03/28/16 for most devices, so you should be able to download the new firmware and install now.** If you still can't install, you likely have one of the few devices that still don't have an updated version of iOS 9.3. You can check your device's signing status [here](https://ipsw.me/).

Comment: There was a bug in 9.3, Apple will release a replacement soon.... so they say.

Comment: That was fixed today. [It was rereleased](https://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/03/apple-pulls-ios-9-3-update-for-older-devices-following-activation-problems/).

Answer (score 1):

If you go on MacRumors forums and other discussion boards, you will see other users also having the same trouble with you. This is the common activation error that just occurred on the iOS 9.3. You can [downgrade back to iOS 9.2](http://appletoolbox.com/2016/01/how-to-downgrade-from-ios-9-3-beta-to-ios-9-2/) or get the [updated version of iOS 9.3 for iPad](http://9to5mac.com/2016/03/24/apple-releases-new-build-of-ios-9-3-for-users-of-older-ios-devices-affected-by-bricking-bug/) (if you have the iPad 2) by connecting your device to a computer with iTunes and Update from  there.

Comment: I do not want to downgrade back to iOS 9.2, since I have not succeeded to install 9.3 in my 9.2.1 device. I want to understand why I cannot update to 9.3 and why new systems do not show recognition of new upgrades.

Comment: I've no idea why that happen. Here is what Apple explained to us: Updating some iOS devices (iPhone 5s and earlier and iPad Air and earlier) to iOS 9.3 can require entering the Apple ID and password used to set up the device in order to complete the software update. In some cases, if customers do not recall their password, their device will remain in an inactivated state until they can recover or reset their password. For these older devices, we have temporarily pulled back the update and will release an updated version of iOS 9.3 in the next few days that does not require this step.

Comment: If the device is an iPad 2, Apple released a new build of 9.3 to fix the bricking issue. If it's a different device, did you forget your user ID or password during setup to 9.3?