# How to downgrade iOS from 9.3.1 to 7.1 (default version)?

Tags: downgrade

I wanna check how my application works for iOS 7.1.
I have got an iPad mini 2. I know it has iOS factory 7.1 . But now it has 9.3.2 (the lates).
Is it possible to reset iPad until the default iOS? How to do it?

Comment: You can simulate recent versions down 8.1 in Xcode

Comment: How? I can't find any simulator previous iOS 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install older versions of iOS (see [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r?lq=1) for details), but you can run the simulator in Xcode with older versions.

- From within an iPad project, go to **Product** -- **Destination** -- **Download Simulators...**
- Pick the version you want

It doesn't go further back than iOS 8.1 though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to install iOS 7.1 from a later version of iOS, such as 9.3.2. That is because Apple stops signing the builds, and even if you have an ipsw file to restore your device, it will not verify. You can check ipsw.me to see what builds are still being signed by Apple (In Green).