# iPhone IOS 7 SHSH blob

Tags: ios

IOS 9.X bricked my last device, so a replacement phone with IOS 7.X arrived.  Before upgrading to the latest 9.X: I am wondering if it is still possible to obtain the SHSH blobs should I wish to go back to 7.X.

Comment: SHSH Blobs, at the moment, are not useful.

Comment: @IronCraftMan: thank you for the comment. Why are they not useful today?  I thought that they were the key to installing older versions of IOS.

Comment: There is no "key to installing older iOS" any more. It cannot be done - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r

Answer (score 1):

iFaith can generate SHSH blobs and turn them into restorable IPSW files!

https://github.com/iH8sn0w/iFaith/releases