# What is a semi-untethered jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I've read about a [semi-untethered jailbreak by Pangu](http://en.pangu.io/help.html). What does semi-tethered mean? What are the differences between that and a normal jailbreak?

I have an iPhone 5 on iOS 7.0.6, and before to try upgrade to 9.3.5, I would like more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semi-untethered Pangu jailbreak [only works on iOS 9.2 to 9.3.3](http://canijailbreak.com), and no, [you cannot upgrade specifically to iOS 9.3.3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387).

But, to answer your question about what a semi-untethered jailbreak means, [taken from the Jailbreak Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/wiki/ios933jailbreakhelp),

> After rebooting your device, your tweaks will not function and your device will appear to not be jailbroken. To fix this, open the Pangu app, lock your phone and wait for it to [refresh].

A normal jailbreak as we know it is called an [untethered jailbreak](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Untethered_jailbreak). Back in the day, there were also [tethered jailbreaks](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Tethered_jailbreak). Tethered meant that every time you rebooted your iOS device, you were *required* to re-jailbreak with a computer (or else your device wouldn't even boot!). Untethered meant that the device can jailbreak itself automatically every time during the boot process. Semi-untethered is a mix between the two - it needs to be jailbroken every time you reboot, but it can be done by an app on the device instead of needing to do it with a computer.

Comment: Thank you for the editing. But the page that i've linked about semi-thethered jailbreak on 9.3.5? it's an error? I know the differences between tethered, unthetered, etc. I thought that was another kind of jailbreak, cause on that web page i've read "semi-jailbreak"! :)

Comment: @strano The link you linked to is not official Pangu and was full of misinformation and potentially malicious. The link I changed it to is official Pangu. **There is no iOS 9.3.5 jailbreak**.

Comment: @strano No problem! I'm just glad you came here first so you didn't get a virus, etc.

Comment: as 2019 you can use phoenix jailbreak as mentioned in https://cydia-app.com/ios-9/

Comment: Yes, according to https://canijailbreak.com/ (which is ran by prominent figures in the jailbreaking community), Phoenix can jailbreak iOS 9.3.5 on 32-bit devices. I would recommend using the website I linked because it does not host the files itself and instead links to the direct sources so you get legitimate untampered software. Phoenix was basically a project to prove that old, never-before-jailbroken firmwares could be jailbroken using modern exploits.