# Can I apply iOS 10 jailbreak if I've already installed 10.0.2?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

My iOS device is updated to 10.0.2. Can I follow the "Untethered Jailbreak" section at pangu8.com/10.html to install the full iOS 10 jailbreak on my device?  I don't care if my device reverts back to 10.0.0 in the process. Just curious if that's even an option.

Comment: Does that site indicate you can apply the jailbreak to 10.0.2?  From looking at that site, it tells you whether or not it can be done.  I don't understand what your question is about?

Comment: my question is related to the section titled "untethered jailbreak", which is not for 10.0.2.

Answer (score 8):

There is no iOS 10 jailbreak available currently. That website is a scam.

---

2017 update: Some versions of iOS 10 are now jailbreakable with [Yalu](https://yalu.qwertyoruiop.com). That website is *still* a scam.

Comment: i don't see how i can accept this answer with some source of information as to i being a scam.   has someone tried their procedures and failed?  i'm talking about the "unthethered jailbreak" section of the article not the jailbreak they're talking about that you install for iOS safari

Comment: @zumalifeguard The website is a scam because there is no iOS 10 jailbreak available currently. Do not install whatever that website suggests, it'll be malware or similar.

Comment: grgarside, I think that the polite thing to do is when you make a statement, have a reference to back up your claim, otherwise you're basically saying, "trust me. i'm right".   Would you blindly believe something someone tells you?  No you wouldn't.   So why would you make the assertion that you're making without some kind of a reference so that others can verify your claim.   I think that's least you could do when you answer a question.  Otherwise, it's just a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @zumalifeguard The source for why that website is a scam *is* because there is no iOS 10 jailbreak. The actual PanGu website is http://en.pangu.io, most definitely not the website you're referring to. To keep up-to-date on the latest jailbreak information, see the subreddit [/r/jailbreak](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/).

Comment: Anyone on the Internet can make any statement whatsoever.  How do I know your statement that "there is no iOS 10 jailbreak" is accurate?

Comment: @zumalifeguard _"Anyone on the Internet can make any statement whatsoever"_ That also goes for that website that claims to have an ios10 jailbreak. How do you know that it is accurate?

Comment: I am not making the claim that it's accurate.   Someone else is making the claim that it is inaccurate.

Comment: @zumalifeguard There was a [similar website linked on a different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252692/what-is-a-semi-untethered-jailbreak). It was also not legitimate. The official Pangu website is http://en.pangu.io/

Answer (score 0):

Pangu team haven't released any jailbreaking tool yet and that page just allows to install a store for apps that doesn't require jailbreak. Although, they are said to release it soon and you will defenetely hear as it becomes available.