# Is it possible to show verbose info on boot/respring?

Tags: startup, jailbreak

I recently jailbroke my IPad mini running 9.3.5 using the Phoenix untethered jailbreak utility. I got some things to work, but I want to have verbose boot output on the startup/respring screen.

Is there any way that this is possible?

If this is helpful,`nvram -p` outputs:

```
obliteration   handle message: Obliteration Complete

auto-boot   true

boot-args   -v <--- This is a parameter for verbose that did not work.

oblit-begins   OblitType: ObliterateDataPartition. No reason given.

backlight-level   1679
```

I hope I can get it to work.

EDIT: It's been days since I posted this and I really want to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `-v` boot arg outputs verbose to some output somewhere like a buffer you could read over USB. It does not print it to the screen. If you want it to print to the screen, you would have to write something yourself that does it. But you're running a [semi-untethered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252692/what-is-a-semi-untethered-jailbreak/252717#252717) jailbreak, so it doesn't actually jailbreak until *after* it's booted (so even writing something yourself wouldn't work). The classic untethered jailbreaks would jailbreak during boot.

Answer (score 1):

There are no ways to boot 9.3.5 iOS in verbose mode I did a lot of research and even pangu can't achieve this you can Google how to verbose boot an iPad but there will be simply no answer because there isn't any release by pangu. You might even see some videos in YouTube in which some people have managed to dual boot and have verbose boot in iOS 10! But the sad part is never reveal it they might have developed the code but some might even get it from unknown sources. So you have to wait until a person or a developer releases an app which can verbose boot  iOS 9.3.5.

Comment: I already did that, proof is the output of ' nvram -p '

Comment: Have you tried running it as root and then type `reboot` in that terminal window?

Comment: I'll try. Just remember that it's an UNTETHERED jailbreak. I need to jailbreak every time I reboot. EDIT: I did it and it did not work.

Comment: I have edited my answer please do take a look at it.