# iPhone - cancel 'swipe to upgrade'?

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade

I recently had to restore a backup of my iPhone and when I booted it up it the only screen I can get is 'swipe to upgrade'.

I'd really love to avoid upgrading past my current software version at the moment, does anyone know if there's a way to cancel the upgrade?

Thanks in advance for your advice :)

Comment: No. If you restore, it will also upgrade to the latest release available that your device can use. Any/all older iOS are no longer being signed by Apple & therefore can no longer be installed. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's the darndest thing but I'm on iOS 9.3.5 after successfully doing a restore! I didn't think this was possible if you had the 'swipe to upgrade' screen happen.

If anyone else happens to be in this situation, the only thing I did out of the usual was reset the phone when it attempted to run the upgrade on the load bar screen, then put it into DFU mode and connect it to iTunes. Nothing else apart from a further reset when I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Did you restore using iTunes or on the device itself?

Comment: The device asked if I wanted to restore from iCloud, iTunes, Transfer from Android or Setup as New. I chose restore from iTunes, then connected the phone and selected my most recent backup from within iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. Sorry this is kinda too short to be an answer, but it is.
Apple stops signing older software short after the release of a new version.

> As of Wednesday Apple is no longer signing iOS 9.3.5, effectively
>   preventing anyone already on iOS 10 from downgrading to iOS 9.

Source: [Apple Insider](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/10/19/apple-stops-signing-ios-935-halting-any-downgrades-from-ios-10)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought this might be the case, I was hoping that since it hadn't actually run the update yet -it does if i swipe though- that I could escape!