# Accidental upgrade of iPhone SE to iOS 10, any way to go back to 9?

Tags: iphone, ios, downgrade

I'm fairly sure this is not possible but had to ask anyway.

My wife's iPhone SE was on iOS 9 which she loved, and she hates iOS 10 (has tried it on my phone and can't stand it).  Today her phone popped up a dialog to upgrade and her finger slipped just enough to hit "OK" rather than "Cancel" (or whatever the precise wording, I forget).  Now she's on iOS 10 and is absolutely miserable.

Is there any possible way to revert?  I'm aware of the new "prometheus" option but as she's never jailbroken or had any interest in such things, she has no saved blobs for her phone from any prior OS version.  I know this is a long shot but... fingers crossed.

Comment: No, this is not possible - see this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102929/168832). As an aside, is there something in particular your wife hates about iOS 10? Perhaps you could ask another question (or questions) about those issues? I've found most users grow to really like iOS 10 after sorting out some initial bugbears.

Comment: Her issues with iOS 10 are nothing that can have anything done about them.  She despises change for change's sake, and iOS 10 (actually every i OS upgrade) is loaded with things that absolutely didn't need to change.  Looks like I'm just going to be stuck with an extremely unhappy partner for a very long time - or go buy a used iPhone SE that still has 9.x on it.  Did it before with her iphone 4s when I accidentally upgraded it to 7, so it's not a new concept for me.  Sigh.