# How do i upgrade my Ipad to a specific software without a computer?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

I have an Ipad that has ios 9.3.3 as the software version and i need your help because i want to update only to ios 11 and to update to ios 12, it says i need a computer so I need your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r) What you want is not possible. Basically your choices are to stay on the iOS you're on, or update to the latest, or the latest supported by your device.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to upgrade to a specific version if your device doesn’t support the latest version or if Apple signs the update, so you can update using iTunes.

All devices that support iOS 11 support iOS 12 so that is not an option.

Apple is no longer signing iOS 11 and hence it isn’t possible to update to it. If you really need iOS 11 you can buy a used/new device online that is running iOS 11, but that is your only option.