# What if I download a different IPSW for a different Device?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I've always been doing research on how to download a firmware for a different device. What i'm trying to say is: What will happen if I download a firmware that is not meant for my device? I downloaded the iPhone 4s iOS 6 IPSW to for my iPhone 6s. Will it not work? Will it brick the device? Will it still work anyway but will the display be stretched? No, i'm not trying to make a duplicate question, I just want to know is going to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r) ...In short, it will simply not install.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is going to happen. It won't take the IPSW file and give an error, something like:

> The iPhone "name" could not be restored

You should just get the iPhone 6s IPSW file. Another note: You can't get iOS 6 on an iPhone 6s. The lowest version is iOS 9 for iPhone 6s.