# Restoring iOS without updating iOS in iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, restore

I have this problem that when I'm trying to restore my iPhone 6 on iTunes it keeps me prompting me that **restore and update** when I'm just choose the **restore** option only, cause I don't want it to update its own iOS to the newer one. Is there a way to avoid updating when I choose the **restore** option only? I already search all the solution online yet no answer help my concern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r) In short, no. Unless your phone is limited to an old iOS, then all you can do is install the latest.

Comment: Which iOS version do you want to restore to ??

Answer (score 1):

You can here: https://ipsw.me/ find the old restore images *(the image will be downloaded from Apple's server)*, which you from iTunes can use for the restore.

To use the downloaded .ipsw file, you hold down the "Option" key, then click "Restore iPhone" in the Summary page in iTunes. Here, you'll see a file browser menu pop up. Locate your downloaded .ipsw file, select it, then click "Open"

Just be aware that it is only signed iOS versions you will be able to install.

Here is a guide, that show the steps: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/downgrade-ios-13-back-ios-12-4-1-your-iphone-using-itunes-finder-0198642/