# Music app of iOS 12 on iOS 13

Tags: ios, jailbreak, music.app

Is it possible to have the music app of iOS 12 on iOS 13, because the interface where the queue can be accessed only by pressing a button rather than scrolling/swiping down is very annoying.

Open to Jailbreaking the device for the same.

Comment: This is very risky and could very likely break your music app, if you attempt to do this. Instead try installing a 3rd party client for Apple Music like SongOwl and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses code signing to lock all their apps to the latest OS version. If you were to jailbreak your phone it might be possible to replace the Music app from a previous version but it would likely cause instability.

A more reliable solution would be to roll back your phone to OS 12. But you’d be trading off the new features from OS 13.

Comment: For 'rolling back' see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r

Comment: I don't wish to give up the epic dark mode and many other great features of iOS 13.