# Accidently upgraded from iOS 13.2 to latest iOS 14, how to revert?

Tags: iphone, ios

iPhone popped the new update ready to install screen and I accidently hit install instead of later as I always do. It's now in the process of installing. How may I revert back to previous 13.2 once installation is complete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r)

Answer (score 2):

[You may not roll back from iOS 14 without a jailbreak.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102929/5472) Sorry to bear news you may not have expected.

- https://9to5mac.com/2020/09/22/ios-14-jailbreak/