# Is Notes sync broken on iOS 14 and macOS Mojave 10.14?

Tags: macos, ios, mojave, data-synchronization, notes.app

I remember that I read somewhere that notes in iOS 14 will not be compatible with notes in Mojave. But I cannot find any more updated information. Some claim that they only stop working after one upgrades the format in which they are saved on iCloud.

Can someone please post their experience/knowledge whether it is safe to upgrade to iOS 14 without losing sync of notes with OSx running Mojave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using iOS 14.4 and macOS 10.14.6 and notes actually sync better as compared to iOS 12.

Keep an eye on apple forums, release notes etc in case other iOS updates break sync.

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes

Downgrading iOS version from backup seems not impossible as per [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r)

So wait for a few weeks before upgrading iOS and see if people are complaining about sync problems.