# Can you update an iPhone from an .ipsw without losing all settings?

Tags: iphone, firmware

I want to upgrade an iPhone SE (1st gen) from iOS 14.3 to 14.8, not iOS 15.

(Evidently, Apple added the code that allows you to stay on the iOS 14 track at a later date, as it only shows options for upgrading to iOS 15.)

I've downloaded the correct .ipsw file and verified the sha1 checksum on [theiphonewiki.com](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware).

Will restoring from that wipe all the settings? (apps, network, home screen layout etc. etc.) and if so, is there any way I can back the settings up first?  Remember I'm upgrading (from 14.3 to 14.8), not downgrading, should that make a difference…

(I am currently running iTunes on macOS Mojave.)

Thanks.

Comment: Apple are still signing 14.8, so an update ought to be fine; you are going 'uphill' which has always been supported; 'downhill', on the other hand never has been [ie 15 back to 14.8] - but I cannot state that categorically, so can't post as an answer. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r for historic & canonical data

Answer (score 1):

You can option-click "Update" instead of "Restore" in iTunes to update your phone instead of wiping and restoring it. The process is almost the same as an OTA update, except for that fact that you're reinstalling the entire OS from the ipsw file. No settings, documents, data, or apps are touched.

Note: you should always have a backup. It doesn't matter if you're doing OTA updates, ipsw updates, or just going outside with your device. If you care about the data and/or settings, back it up. In fact, I'm pretty sure iTunes will automatically back up your device before applying an update.