# How to downgrade from iOS 16.1.2 to 15.x?

Tags: ios

How can I downgrade my iPhone XR from iOS 16.1.2 to 15.x?

This is given that

- I don't have a backup of the iPhone on my laptop made with any iOS version prior to 16.1.2, and
- Apple doesn't sign .ipsw files for the iPhone XR for iOS versions previous to 16.

Note: my problem is different from the one that was asked about in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r) in 2013, because iOS 15 was installed on my phone until a few hours ago. The info in the first answer to that question about the reasons for Apple's rapid discontinuation of signing is interesting, though. Something may well have changed in nine years.

Further note: I think this question got closed before I managed to post the above edit.

Comment: The backup is OS independent. If you restore it is applied over the current OS, not the one current at the time it was saved. Once Apple stops signing an OS version, there's no practical way back to ti.

Comment: Your problem might be slightly different (but the lack of a backup kind of makes it the same anyway), but the solution (or lack thereof) is the same.